# How to send_keys with in a textarea using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I need to send a comment in the field. It works with "input", but not with "textarea". Someone had to deal with this?

Before clicking on the Html element it looks like:

```
<textarea class = '1' aria-label="Add a comment..." placeholder="Add a comment..."autocomplete="off"  autocorrect="off"> </textarea>
```

Then:

```
<textarea class = '1 focus-visible' aria-label="Add a comment..." placeholder="Add a comment..."autocomplete="off"  autocorrect="off" style="height: 18px;"  data-focus-visible-added = ""> </textarea>
```

The textarea field is activated, but no comment is added.

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('textarea[placeholder="Add a comment..."]').send_keys('comment')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send a *character sequence* to the *text area* you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "textarea.1[aria-label^='Add a comment'][placeholder^='Add a comment']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "textarea.1.focus-visible[aria-label^='Add a comment'][placeholder^='Add a comment'][data-focus-visible-added]"))).send_keys("Алекс")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//textarea[starts-with(@aria-label, 'Add a comment') and starts-with(@placeholder, 'Add a comment')][@class='1']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//textarea[starts-with(@aria-label, 'Add a comment') and starts-with(@placeholder, 'Add a comment')][@class='1 focus-visible' and @data-focus-visible-added]"))).send_keys("Алекс")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you mean but for me this code works perfectly fine

```
class Bot():
    def __init__(self):
       self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    def comment(self):
       self.driver.get(url)
       self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('textarea[placeholder="Add a comment..."]').send_keys('comment')

bot = Bot()
bot.comment()
```

It write in this element on my web page:

```
<textarea class = '1' aria-label="Add a comment..." placeholder="Add a comment..."autocomplete="off"  autocorrect="off"> </textarea>
```